# Easy transition between static and dynamic library within Cocoa Framework

Tags: xcode, cocoa, build, frameworks, ios8

I've created a Framework starting with the "Cocoa Touch Framework" project type (on iOS 8.1), and when I was done I ended up with a dynamic library that worked fine.

However for certain cases I also need a framework which has a static library inside of it. I have seen pages describing the entire manual process in detail (creating the Framework directory structure, etc.) but since I already have a project for my framework I'm hoping there is some flag or setting I can adjust to just drop in a static framework instead of a dynamic one.

If anyone can let me know how I can adjust my Framework's project settings to do this please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was much easier than I expected, simply change "Mach-O Type" under "Build Settings" from "Dynamic Library" to "Static Library"